# How do I join 2 columns from 2 tables into a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have 3 tables:

Table1:

```
app_id| reference
-----------------
123   | table2
124   | table3
```

Table2:

```
app_id| info
-----------------
123   | test app1
```

Table3:

```
app_id| app_info
-----------------
124   | test app2
```

**Question**: how do I make SQL to return this table below?

```
app_id| information
-----------------
123   | test app1
124   | test app2
```

I can write a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.app_id, t2.info, t3.app_info
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.app_id = t2.app_id
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t1.app_id = t3.app_id
```

But I don't want t2.info, t3.app_info as 2 separate fields, I want it to return single 'information' column with joined data from both tables.

Comment: Your desired result for the sample data is simply `table1 union all table2`

Answer (score 2):

Would add the `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT t1.app_id, coalesce(t2.info, t3.app_info) information
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.app_id = t2.app_id
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t1.app_id = t3.app_id
;
```

• [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5edaa4/4) (MS SQL Server 2017)
• Documentation to [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)